# swift: returning a child node with the same position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, sprite, skspritenode

I have Two Sprite nodes in a function from a swift file. Both nodes are similar in size and position. Node2 is a child of node.

When the nodes are added to the scene, the nodes position are different from each other. They are not on top of each other like they are supposed to be.

```
func stoppers()->SKSpriteNode{   
 let node=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"image1")
    node.size=CGSize(width:20,height:300)
    node.position=CGPoint(x:100,y:100)

    let node2=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"image2")
    node2.size=CGSize(width:20,height:300)
    node2.position=CGPoint(x:100,y:100)

node.addChild(node2)
return node
}
```

the function is called to the scene like: 
           addChild(game.stoppers())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `node2` is a child of `node1` and you want them to be in the same place on screen, then `node2` must have a `position` of `(x: 0, y: 0)`. This is because the position of a child node is relative to the parent node. They also need to have the same `anchorPoint`.

Comment: Bear in mind that there are other considerations for child nodes e.g. they move and scale with their parent and effects and forces that affect the parent will also have an effect on the child (children).